# $do_not_duplicate is not working in genesis theme

Tags: loop, genesis-theme-framework, globals, post-duplication

I'm using Genesis child theme and I am using this function to display feature posts on home page.

```
function modern_motoroids_extra_feature_posts(){ ?>
        <?php $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>
        <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
        <?php query_posts( array('meta_key' => 'feature-story', 'orderby'=> 'date', 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ), 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate)); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_id(); ?>
             <?php echo get_the_titke(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php }
add_action('genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap','modern_motoroids_extra_feature_posts');
```

Then I am using this function to show latest posts on the same page.

```
function latest_feature_posts(){ ?>
        <?php $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>
        <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
        <?php query_posts( array('orderby'=> 'date', 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ), 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate)); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_id(); ?>
             <?php echo get_the_titke(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php }
add_action('genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap','latest_feature_posts');
```

Problem is Its still showing duplicate posts, even after using `$do_not_duplicat`. I tried to search on google and stackoverflow but didn't get anything. Please help me. Whay these functions are showing duplicate posts? and how to exclude them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Instead of all that, you could just use a meta_query and "NOT IN" to exclude the feature stories from your second query. That's the easiest answer.

Check out [this meta query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) for help.

---

1, you need to have do_not_duplicate be a global array in order access it across functions (pretty sure).

2, you are overwriting it at the beginning of each function with `<?php $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>`

Try taking out the part where you declare it as an array in whichever function comes 2nd. Instead echo it out to the console using this: `//Debug in console
echo '<script>  console.dir(' . json_encode($do_not_duplicate) . '); </script>';`
Hold on to that little piece of code, it has made my life so much easier for debugging variables and such.

If that doesn't work, declare the $do_not_duplicate as a global variable, and that should get the job done.